# What is meaning of negative value of features of images extracted using pretrained network

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

For 346 Images I got 4096 features which are extracted with the help of pre-trained model Alexnet (concept of Transfer learning is used).
What does these negative value represents?
Is it okay if I either convert those negative values to zero or positive?

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eOfb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a relu activation to the extracted features (setting negative values to 0), you’ll simply be working with a different extracted feature set, which may or may not work fine depending on the problem and the classifier you are using.

Some frameworks consider FC + relu to be one layer, in which case those 4096 activations from an FC + relu layer would all be non-negative, some consider FC to be one layer and the relu after to be a second layer, in which case you should extract from the layer you are interested in. So, in the final AlexNet layers you are extracting features from, the issue here is a matter of convention of whether you consider the features from the conv layer or the features from the relu layer after the conv. Neither of these approaches is wrong, each just corresponds to different features.

Comment: Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

you are transforming your data from mxn to 4096x1 space, where you can have arbitrary number for each element, depending your transformation. So you should see that as a different data, regardless of non-negative pixel values.